# Code being slower after MacOS 14.0 (Sonoma) Update

Tags: python, macos, pysimplegui

Last week I was testing my code and it was working fine. However, after I updated to MacOS Sonoma it significantly slowed down. I am using the packages:

```
-> pyvo==1.4 
-> numpy==1.22.0
-> pandas==1.5.3 
-> astropy==5.2.2
-> truncate==0.11 
-> requests==2.28.1 
-> astroquery==0.4.6 
-> matplotlib==3.5.0 
-> PySimpleGUI==4.60.4 
-> OpenCV-python==4.7.0.72
-> beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
-> astro-datalab== 2.20.1
```

The main issue that I am having is that my buttons are not registering my clicks on my PySimpleGUI update. Every time I launch the GUI it returns this in my terminal: "Mac OS Version is 14.0 and patch enabled so applying the patch".

Is this standard for new MacOS updates? Or there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Experience is a great teacher, unfortunately. When there is a new OS release, there will be bugs and performance changes which will impact some third party software. If you don't want to be bitten by them, you wait to perform your upgrade, and keep an eye on the libraries you use for issues and bug-fixes, so you can upgrade the libraries before you upgrade your OS. There may be fixes in newer versions of the libraries you're using already, so checking for upgrades may be an option here. New software releases mean new features… and *new bugs*, it's not just the Mac.

Comment: The "patch" is from PySimpleGUI because of problems with M1 releases.  For PySimpleGUI support, open an issue on the project's GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue right after updating to Sonoma. Buttons did not react on clicking most of the time. Even the PySimpleGui sample Demo_All_Widgets.py was not really useable. After installing Python 3.12.0 everything seems to be correct again. I was using 3.9.6 before and tried it with a newer 3.9 version as well as 3.10 - no success. 3.12 looks good for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer -- it shouldn't be considered "standard" but rather "likely" for the upgrade of Mac OS (or any operating system or platform you are building on top of).

Unless the libraries you are using (and your code for that matter) have been updated/re-optimized for the new platform, it is likely that performance will change.  Sometimes for the better, but we only seem to remember the times when it gets worse :)

Looking at the list of libraries you provided, it would be difficult for anyone to positively identify the Mac OS as the definite cause, barring an open issue for one of the libraries resembling: "performance problems reported for version X.Y.Z on Sonoma".

My suggestion is to spend some time profiling, and try to find the source of the degradation.  From there, you can post a specific question about the degradation and/or connect with other consumers of the library.  If you have the ability to do an A/B comparison before/after the update that would be very helpful in diagnosing the issue.